# Why Whittaker functions are useful?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Whittaker functions appears in Langlands program. Recently, it is shown that some Whittaker functions can be obtained by integrating a function related to decoration over a geometric crystal in http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0902 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5451.

My questions are

(1) Why Whittaker function are useful?

(2) It seems that using geometric crystals to obtain Whittaker functions are quite explicit. What are the usual method to compute Whittaker function in number theory?

(3) If we have a Whittaker model, how could we obtain an L-function from it?

Thank you very much.